# Running Ruby on Rails in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I really want to learn Ruby on Rails and I have heard it is a great community so hopefully someone can help with this. Couldn't find any direct answering this already but if there is one I'm sure someone will close this and point me in the right direction.

Is it possible to create Ruby on Rails applications from just a browser? I have bought a book and want the easiest possible way to do the exercises and experiment with building some applications, try Gems etc. I know the greatest chance of success is if I can do this when I have a spare 30 minutes ideally on my iPad.

As I am also looking at learning node.js I have signed upto Duostack and Joyent but both still need SSH setup, Github install etc. I'm looking for something that is just in a browser Window, I can write code and see it execute without having to setup any infrastructure. Found this on HackerNews today (reticular activation system?): http://bellard.org/jslinux/ . Looks promising will need to play with it to see if I can get Ruby on Rails working there but HN comments say no Internet connection so maybe not.

I do have a small netbook which I am going to run Ubuntu on which I guess is the other option but carrying this around will reduce my chances of success.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Cloud9 IDE](http://cloud9ide.com/)? It's an IDE in a browser. I've not had a chance to try it out myself, so can't promise it'll do the trick. I think the primary limitation is going to be actually /running/ the code. I think Cloud9 supports Node.js, but obviously that's not going to help when you're coding a rails app.

You might also want to look at their [editor](http://ace.ajax.org/) (which forms just /part/ of the overall offering).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly create application from browser but if you want to really start rails then you can quickly start using scaffold.installed rail gem on your system and start with the following command

```
rails application_name
```

go to the application and run below command

```
ruby script/generate scaffold users
```

then run `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate`

run your server using `ruby script/server`

it will start on port 3000 by default.

you can check it on browser using `http://localhost:3000/`

Note `all above code is written in rails 2.x version`

Comment: Thanks @Hitesh . Seems easy enough but guess that is for the netbook and Ubuntu option? Install ruby and rails (I can google that) and then run those commands to get a webserver up and running?

Answer (score -1):

If you have a server up and running, you could use SSH through a Webapp (I'm sure there are some open source solutions available) to create your application, use rake, the scripts and so on. Also you can use nano/VI/whatever to edit your codefiles.
This way it is possible to do it with an ipad, but I would definetly prefer the netbook since it is **MUCH** more easy to code this way!

Comment: yeah thats my backup option. Thought I would investigate whether I could do it in browser first. Something like tryruby.org lessons for Rails but where you can do your own apps would be ideal